# How to Export EE v 1.6.7 pages

Tags: export

Here at work we're using EE v.1.6.7 and will be moving to a new proprietary CMS, I'm looking for a way to export the individual pages to a spreadsheet - the new web company we will be working with have asked for our existing pages to be in an excel ss...is this even possible???  I am not an Expression Engine expert. Please speak slowly and clearly to me. ;) Thanks.

Comment: Ermmm.. You should send a developer over here. It'll be hard to find any addons compatible with EE 1.6.7 that do what you want, and most of us have zero access to such and old version, that this will be a custom job anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible. On the assumption that yours is a standard EE install, you can export the data from the database by running specific SQL queries to pull the data out in the format they want (table joins required). I suggest that you get the new web company to clarify what Excel column headers they want, to enable you(?) to construct the query to format the data. Then export the results in CSV format.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's any need to use any add-ons for this or resort to SQL queries.

You can just create new EE templates with exp:weblog:entries calls that produce output that can be saved in .CSV format (which can be opened in Excel).

If you update your question with some more details on what fields you have in EE and what you need in Excel I can update this answer with more complete details.